# Is there an idiomatic way to open a graphical terminal in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, x11

I've got some bash scripts that open graphical terminals (Gnome-terminal, LXTerminal, Konsole etc).

However I wonder if there exists an idiomatic way to open a terminal? Something like the XDG standard for file types?  Otherwise I'm hard coding a reference with the specific way to open a terminal, for example:

```
lxterminal -e "ls"
```

A neater way would be to have an 'openTerminal' function I suppose, that takes the command to run as one of the parameters.

Comment: I think the canonical solution would be to permit the user to configure the terminal command through a config file or environment variable, and default to something like `xterm`.

Answer (score 2):

Debian does this with the [`x-terminal-emulator`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/x-terminal-emulator) *virtual package*, described in *[11.8.3 Packages providing a terminal emulator](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#s11.8.3)*

> Packages that provide a terminal emulator for the X Window System which meet the criteria listed below should declare in their Provides control field that they provide the virtual package **`x-terminal-emulator`**. They should also register themselves as an alternative for `/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator`, with a priority of 20. That alternative should have a slave alternative for `/usr/share/man/man1/x-terminal-emulator.1.gz` pointing to the corresponding manual page.
>
> To be an x-terminal-emulator, a program must:
>
> - Be able to emulate a DEC VT100 terminal, or a compatible terminal.
> - Support the command-line option -e command, which creates a new terminal window[106] and runs the specified command, interpreting the entirety of the rest of the command line as a command to pass straight to exec, in the manner that xterm does.
> - Support the command-line option -T title, which creates a new terminal window with the window title title.

That is, the policy describes a *minimal* compatibility with xterm from the mid-1990s.

It's been of limited success:

- some packagers abuse the priority field, using values well above 20.
- the **`-e`** option compatibility is poor with some of the terminals you've mentioned.

Aside from Debian (and derived distributions such as Ubuntu), that approach is not used much.

I recall answering this before, but do not see it at the moment.  Here is a listing from my Debian/testing, noting that each of the packages with **`40`** priority does not follow the policy:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/xterm-dev                60        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/evilvte                  20        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/konsole                  40        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/lxterminal               40        manual mode
  7            /usr/bin/mate-terminal.wrapper    30        manual mode
  8            /usr/bin/mlterm                   20        manual mode
  9            /usr/bin/mrxvt-full               10        manual mode
  10           /usr/bin/pterm                    20        manual mode
  11           /usr/bin/stterm                   15        manual mode
  12           /usr/bin/terminology              40        manual mode
  13           /usr/bin/urxvt                    20        manual mode
  14           /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  15           /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  16           /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode
  17           /usr/bin/xterm-dev                60        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

(The "xterm-dev" package is of course a local development package, not published).